# SD card fragment in card slot

Tags: sd-card

I was taking the Raspberry Pi sd card out when the sd broke, putting those little plastic lines on the sd card in the slot. I got them out, except one of the parts is stuck in the edge. IT IS NOT THE SD CARD SLOT THAT IS BROKEN. Any ideas on how to remove the chips?

Edit: Thanks. I will post a picture as soon as the camera is done charging. By the way, the chip is lodged in the non-angled corner of the Pi's sd slot, and is wedge shaped, and is behind the contacts.

Edit: Picture at https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2Ibc.jpg

Comment: hard to tell (you could add a photo to make it clearer (use http://imgur.com)) - You could use tweezers (or even pliers) could be used to *carefully* tease the broken bits out - SD cards don't usually break that easily...

Comment: Take a picture and post it.

Comment: I posted  the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. disconnect power
2. try to remove the piece using tweezers (just as @Wilf's comment suggested) or even using toothpicks (fun fact: you wouldn't believe how useful toothpicks are in the lab for numerous applications)
3. blow with dry air to remove small fragments
4. visual inspection
5. insert SD card, connect power, boot up, have fun (hopefully)

Comment: **Don't use compressed air!** It could damage the lifted connectors. Plus, it's not usually an awesome idea to have flying shards of plastic.

Comment: Well, @Jacobm001, while I did not write *compressed* air, I would go so far to claim that it should work - it's all a question of proportioning, just do not place the nozzle directly at the connector.

Comment: @Jacobm001 What's wrong with compressed air? I used it several times to blow dust off the keyboard, and it was pretty safe. Perhaps you wanted to say one shouldn't try to do this with industrial-grade compressor at 1MPa pressure, then I'm with you.